# Function URL display records irrespective of an error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a python lambda function that connects to dynamoDB. The following line is causing an error in cloudatch.

```
response_list = client.scan(
ExpressionAttributeValues = {":nitin_nature": {'N':search_term}}, 
FilterExpression='id = :nitin_nature', 
TableName='activitylg', 
ProjectionExpression='#ST, #AT', 
ExpressionAttributeNames={ '#AT': 'dt', '#ST': 'code', },
```

Error is:

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Scan operation: ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value for key :nitin_nature
```

But the fact is that it shows the correct records (using function URL) even if there is an error.
I am not sure how does the function even completes :)

I can ignore the error since I get the correct expected records. But I will like to know the reason.

Comment: id (Number) is Partition key, dt (Number) is Sort key and code is just the numeric value that needs to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is telling your that `search_term` is not convertible to a Number type in DynamoDB.

If your using the low level client, which I assume you are based on syntax, then ensure that `search_term` is a string value that represents a number. It cannot contain Null or None, as it must always be convertible to a Number type.

Comment: That does not explain how and why am I getting the correct results.

Comment: You wouldn't get the correct results with that exception. It's likely you invoke the function multiple times and one with correct values and one with corrupt values.

Comment: Here is the complete log for just one hit.  
https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/7fb0d350623560a37a5cc267b613b94b

As can be seen, the query returned correctly only 2 times out of 4.

Comment: Catch the exception and print the value of `search_term` when it's thrown.